# javaoctave jar file has failed in Mac OSX Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, octave

Hi I am currently using Eclipse Kepler for my java project.

I wanted to use the Octave (the open sourced MatLab) for calculation. Therefore I have tried to use the javaoctave [(https://kenai.com/projects/javaoctave](https://kenai.com/projects/javaoctave)) to help me do the calculation in java. However, when I want to compile my code I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" dk.ange.octave.exception.OctaveIOException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "octave": error=2, No such file or directory
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExec.<init>(OctaveExec.java:102)
    at dk.ange.octave.OctaveEngine.<init>(OctaveEngine.java:65)
    at dk.ange.octave.OctaveEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(OctaveEngineFactory.java:49)
    at learn.CapabilityLearner.connectOctave(CapabilityLearner.java:72)
    at learn.CapabilityLearner.connect(CapabilityLearner.java:37)
    at learn.CapabilityLearner.<init>(CapabilityLearner.java:24)
    at learn.capability.CapabilityMeanVarianceEquation.<init>(CapabilityMeanVarianceEquation.java:10)
    at parse.basketball.runner.GetPlayerFrequency.learnSynergyGraph(GetPlayerFrequency.java:102)
    at parse.basketball.runner.GetPlayerFrequency.main(GetPlayerFrequency.java:94)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "octave": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.processException(ProcessBuilder.java:478)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:457)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExec.<init>(OctaveExec.java:100)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
    ... 10 more
```

This java project has been successfully run on a Windows machine with Eclipse Kepler so I think it is not the code I have that contains an error. the [wiki](https://kenai.com/projects/javaoctave/lists/general-discussion/archive/2014-02/message/2) has mentioned the error and some explanation is given. However, due to my lack of experience with programming I could not have grasped the meaning of the solutions. Can anyone help me to identify the problem and teach me how I shall fix this?

With many thanks ! :)

PS : the .classpath of the project is as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="matlabcontrol-4.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="javaoctave-0.6.4.jar" sourcepath="javaoctave-0.6.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="commons-math-2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Plus it says that source is not found but I think it is because i used the compiled jar file so that I could not view the source code. But I don't think that's the reason for this error.

Comment: What's is inside your .classpath file in the project folder? (Edit your question and put it there)

Comment: @Kyllopardiun I have added the .classpath file

Answer (score 2):

You can easily solve your problem setting up the Factory

```
OctaveEngineFactory factory = new OctaveEngineFactory();
factory.setOctaveProgram(new File("path_to_octave_executable"));
OctaveEngine octave = factory.getScriptEngine();
```

bgcode