# {Cannot run program "octave"} in Windows Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, path, octave, ioexception

Peace be upon you,

In the following page, a user had a problem in executing his JavaOctave code (my problem is similar to his)

https://kenai.com/projects/javaoctave/lists/general-discussion/archive/2009-12/message/1

I saw that the JavaOctave responsible has spoken about "Configuring the PATH variable to include a path to Octave". But I do not have access to any "Octave.class" file (in their site download part it seems that there is no access to *.class files) so I cannot set the path for pointing out to that object; also, when I set the path to ";...\backups" (the folder containing the "javaoctave-0.6.4.jar"), my problem would not be solved and again I receive

```
Exception in thread "main" dk.ange.octave.exception.OctaveIOException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "octave": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExec.<init>(OctaveExec.java:102)
at dk.ange.octave.OctaveEngine.<init>(OctaveEngine.java:65)
at dk.ange.octave.OctaveEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(OctaveEngineFactory.java:49)
at edu.udg.agentlab.moviervkb.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "octave": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExec.<init>(OctaveExec.java:100)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 6 more
```

I also used the suggestion in this question:
[javaoctave jar file has failed in Mac OSX Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456795/javaoctave-jar-file-has-failed-in-mac-osx-eclipse)

but it couldn't help me and a similar error repeated (the asked question was not occurred in Windows):

```
Exception in thread "main" dk.ange.octave.exception.OctaveIOException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "path_to_octave_executable": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Can anyone help me run my JavaOctave program in my editor (Eclipse) or in any other editor?

Answer (score 1):

> But I do not have access to any "Octave.class"

The mentioned link is not about a *.class file, but some kind of binary for the Windows function CreateProcess. You need some kind of binary and make that available using either PATH in your Eclipse run configuration or to your user in general or whatever. That's surely your real problem, that you are either missing an *.exe or that's CreateProcess can*t find it. You can read the documentation for CreateProcess where it looks for binaries.

[CreateProcess in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also added the path for the octave program c:\sofware\Octave-3.6.4\bin\octave.exe; but no benefit, again!

Comment: The PATH env variable 1. doesn't contain file paths, but the parent directories of the executables and 2. you may need to restart eclipse to get the newly setted PATH recognized. So the proper configuration would be c:\sofware\Octave-3.6.4\bin.

Comment: I exactly wrote c:\sofware\Octave-3.6.4\bin at the beginning of my PATH variable and restarted the Eclipse but no benefit again!

Comment: Finally, it was solved by setting PATH in environment tab of the Eclipse run configuration.

Comment: That's exactly what I've written in my answer before. :-)